# How Can I Add Info Using One Form Into Two Mysql Tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, phpmyadmin

i usualy use the map method to add from the form to the table but now i wont to add from the same form into two tables how can i do that

i tryed && between two map's but it didnt work what else can i try

```
  {books.map((book)=> (
        <div key={book.id} className="book">
          <img src={book.cover} alt="" />
          <h2>{book.title}</h2>
          <p>{book.desc}</p>`your text`
              //here i wont the price to come from Prices.price
          <span>${book.price}</span>
          <button className="delete" onClick={() => handleDelete(book.id)}>Delete</button>
          <button className="update">
          <Link
            to={`/update/${book.id}`}
            style={{ color: "inherit", textDecoration: "none" }}
          >
            Update
          </Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    ))}
    this code add into one table but i have two 
          const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
          const [prices,setPrices]= useState([]);
```